# What is a good way to check if a screen is modified?

Tags: wpf, data-binding, caliburn.micro

Could you please suggest an elegant way to check if a data on the view has been modified to enable the Save button accordingly?

Thanks.

Comment: what screen are you talking about? are you using mvvm? it's relatively easy in mvvm and elegant.

Comment: Yes, I use Caliburn.micro, as you can see in my tags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you are using MVVM with Caliburn.micro, there is a Can-convention for commands. So, assuming you want to enable Save button if a string property named Username is non-empty, you simply add this method to the viewmodel:

```
public bool CanSave()
{
    if(String.IsNullOrEmpty(UserName))
        return false;

    return true;
}
```

Assuming your class inherits PropertyChangedBase or Screen, and you have a button with Name="Save", it will be disabled if UserName is empty. If you are interested in data changing in the view, the relevant property, in this example UserName, would of course have to be bound to some input area in the view - you could for instance have a TextBox named UserName which would make Caliburn set up the binding by convention.

The class in its entirety would then look something like this:

**Edited to only allow saving of actually different data**

```
public class UserViewModel : PropertyChangedBase
{
    private string _savedUserName;

    public string UserName{ get; set; }

    public bool CanSave()
    {
        return !UserName.Equals(_savedUserName);
    }

    public void Save()
    {
        //Save the data

        _savedUserName = UserName;
    }
}
```

Comment: You see, if I edit a record, and the field is not empty, I still don't want to be able to save, unless something has been changed.

Comment: Well, then you would have to keep the original value somehow, to ensure the Save button remains disabled when the value is the same as the saved version. I'll update my answer with a suggestion.

Comment: There might be a way to make it cleaner - but essentially you can't get away from the fact that you need to know what the persisted value is to know if you can enable the button. So either you keep a copy of the persisted value or you have to query the data storage each time.

Comment: I understand, I just hoped maybe Caliburn.Micro had something built in.